# Does the teaser image need to be a picture in the paper?

Tags: peer-review, journal-workflow

I am submitting a paper to a journal.  The journal requires submission of a teaser image.

> Please also identify a teaser image from your manuscript that may be
> used in the abstract book as part of the OnlinePlus program and upload
> this image file with your revision & summary of changes. Name the file
> "Teaser" and select "Image" as the file designation on the File Upload
> screen.

The pictures in my paper are mostly plots of experimental data. Therefore, does the teaser image I upload need to be selected from the paper? Can I draw a picture that is not in the new paper to describe my paper? The length limit of the paper prevents me from adding new pictures.

Really thanks!!!

Comment: You need to ask the editor. We can't make a ruling on what is allowed or not. But "from your manuscript" seems clear enough.

Comment: Also, look in the journal to see what previous authors have done.

Comment: The phrase "from your manuscript" seems pretty clear to me.